# push Object in array in $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery

Maybe I'm just blind, but I'm struggling for a good amount of time now:

I have a small piece of JS-Code here:

```
var linkInput = $('#Link input.gwt-TextBox').val();
var parentRow = $('#Link').parent().parent();
var links = linkInput.split("|");

// hide text-input
$(parentRow).hide();

// get rid of empty elements
links = links.filter(Boolean);

var aSites = [];
var oSite = {};

$(links).each(function (k, v) {

    splits = v.split(".");
    domainName = splits[1];
    oSite.name = domainName;
    oSite.url = v;
    aSites.push(oSite);
});

console.log(aSites);
```

To specify: Get the value of an `input`-field, hide the row afterwards and save all the values in an object, which is then pushed into an array.

The parameter, taken from the console-tab of google Chrome:

```
var links = ["www.myshop1.de/article/1021581", "https://www.myshop2.de/article/1021581"] [type: object]
```

I thought, I iterate through all elements of this object (in that case 2 times), push the values into an object and the object into an array, to have access to all of them afterwards.

At some point however, I seem to override my former values, since my output looks like this:

```
0: {name: "myshop1", url: "https://www.myshop1.de/1021581"}
1: {name: "myshop2", url: "https://www.myshop2.de/1021581"}
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Where is my mistake here? Is there a smarter way to realize this?

**On a sidenote:**

I tried to use only an array (without adding an object), but it seems like I 
can't use an associative key like this:

```
var myKey = "foo";
var myValue = "bar";
myArray[myKey] = myValue
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should move this:

```
var oSite = {};
```

...inside the `each` callback below it, because you need a *new* object in each iteration.

Otherwise you are mutating the same object again and again, pushing the *same* object repeatedly to the `aSites` array, which ends up with multiple references to the *same* object.

Not related, but you can use `$.map` to create your array (or vanilla JS `links.map()`):

```
var aSites = $.map(links, function(v) {
    return { name: v.split(".")[1], url: v };
});
```

Comment: sigh .. I knew it would be something trivial. Thank you! That did it. I'll accept this answer as soon as I can.

Comment: or use `asites.push({ name: ..., url: ... });`